# Save Keras model on hdfs

Tags: tensorflow, keras, save, hdfs

Our company's cloud server only allows us to save files to hdfs. Is there a way to save a Keras model on hdfs. I tried model.save and it won't work.

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow. You need to provide all the details and 
mention the issue clearly (error message?). Please refer the
[ask] link for more detail and update your question accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there's no way to do it directly with Keras. But there are different ways to approach the problem:

1. A transparent method would be to mount the HDFS as a local file system. You don't mention any operating system but seems quite feasible:

   - Using Linux you can use: https://github.com/microsoft/hdfs-mount
   - Mac&Linux: https://pypi.org/project/fuse-webhdfs/
   - Windows: not sure if possible but it is mentions here: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/HADOOP2/MountableHDFS
2. A programmatically approach would be to store to serialize your model to YAML and use a HDFS client for python to save it into the hadoop file system. Here you can find an example for [serializing/deserializing the model](https://machinelearningmastery.com/save-load-keras-deep-learning-models/) and here how to [write&read to hdfs](https://hdfscli.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart.html#reading-and-writing-files) from Python using a HDFSCli package.
3. Finally, you could store the model locally and put it into HDFS using a local hdfs client from the command line if installed. You can invoke it directly from python.